# Canvas only shows on inspect element

Tags: java, gwt, canvas

I'm working with a project where i use [Lienzo](http://www.emitrom.com/lienzo) for canvas manupulation. And some-why when i reload my app, it only renders the canvas in a browser when i click "Inspect element"
My code:

```
public Leinzo(){
    Window.setMargin("0px");
    int width = Window.getClientWidth();
    int height = Window.getClientHeight();

    // initialize the panel
    lienzoPanel = new LienzoPanel(width, height);
    initWidget(lienzoPanel);
    canvas = new Layer();



    final Picture pic = new Picture("images/test.jpg", false, null);
    pic.onLoad(new PictureLoadedHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureLoaded(Picture picture) {
            canvas.add(pic); 
        }         
    });  
    lienzoPanel.add(canvas);
}
```

tried in FF and Chrome. There are now errors shown anywhere.
EDIT: Resizing of the window will make the canvas appear. When i look at the dom it exists there all the time, but browser won't render ..

Answer (score 0):

Add `canvas.draw();` to the `onPictureLoaded` call.